# Displaying custom posts by category

Tags: custom-post-types

I can get custom posts to display on  my site.  However, I want to filter the posts by category.

The custom posts are displaying on this page: 
http://www.africanhealthleadership.org/resources/toolkit/

The custom posts are the tools i.e. Desk Research and Assessment Tool

Under Preparation, I only want to show Desk Research.  However ALL the tools are displaying under Preparation.

I used this code to get the tools to display. Clearly category_name is not working, but I am not sure how to fix. Thank you for any help.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'category_name' => 'preparation' ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific?do you mean `custom post type` or `custom query`?

AFAIK when using custom post type you cannot directly use `category_name` since your post are treated in different way. You have to add custom taxonomies in [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and then register them with [register_taxonomy()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

*note: please correct me if my statement above is wrong, I'm not go deep with custom post type, at least for now.*

say you have custom post type named `portfolio`, custom taxonomy named `toolkit` with following categories:

1. preparation
2. assessment
3. leadership
4. innovation

and you want to show all post in `preparation`:

---

**beware lurker, this code is [severely outdated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762)**

---

```
<?php
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'toolkit' => 'preparation' ) );
  //the loop start here
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```