# When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts, pre-get-posts

I read [@nacin's](https://twitter.com/nacin) [You don't know Query](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012) yesterday and was sent down a bit of a querying rabbit hole. Before yesterday, I was (wrongly) using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for all my querying needs. Now I'm a little bit wiser about using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query), but still have some gray areas.

**What I think I know for sure:**

If I'm making *additional* loops anywhere on a page—in the sidebar, in a footer, any kind of "related posts", etc—I want to be using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). I can use that repeatedly on a single page without any harm. (right?).

**What I don't know for sure**

1. When do I use [@nacin's](https://twitter.com/nacin) [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) vs. [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)? Should I use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for everything now?
2. When I want to modify the loop in a template page — lets say I want to modify a taxonomy archive page — do I remove the `if have_posts : while have_posts : the_post` part and write my own [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)?  Or do I modify the output using [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in my functions.php file?

**tl;dr**

The tl;dr rules I'd like to draw from this are:

1. Never use [`query_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) anymore
2. When running multiple queries on a single page, use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)
3. When modifying a loop, do this __________________.

Thanks for any wisdom

Terry

ps: I have seen and read: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) Which adds another dimension — [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). But doesn't deal with [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should you use WP\_Query vs query\_posts() vs get\_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: @saltcod, now is different, WordPress evolved, I added few comments in comparison to the accepted answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/250523#250523).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You are right to say:

> Never use `query_posts` anymore

#### pre_get_posts

[`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is a filter, for altering **any** query. It is most often used to alter only the 'main query':

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse50761_alter_query');
function wpse50761_alter_query($query){

      if( $query->is_main_query() ){
        //Do something to main query
      }
}
```

(I would also check that `is_admin()` returns *false* - though this may be redundant.). The main query appears in your templates as:

```
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
       //The loop
    endwhile;
endif;
```

If you ever feel the need to edit this loop - use `pre_get_posts`. i.e. If you are tempted to use `query_posts()` - use `pre_get_posts` instead.

#### WP_Query

The main query is an important instance of a [`WP_Query object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). WordPress uses it to decide which template to use, for example, and any arguments passed into the url (e.g. pagination) are all channelled into that instance of the `WP_Query` object.

For secondary loops (e.g. in side-bars, or 'related posts' lists) you'll want to create your own separate instance of the `WP_Query` object. E.g.

```
$my_secondary_loop = new WP_Query(...);
if( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ):
    while( $my_secondary_loop->have_posts() ): $my_secondary_loop->the_post();
       //The secondary loop
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Notice `wp_reset_postdata();` - this is because the secondary loop will override the global `$post` variable which identifies the 'current post'. This essentially resets that to the `$post` we are on.

#### get_posts()

This is essentially a wrapper for a separate instance of a `WP_Query` object. This returns an array of post objects. The methods used in the loop above are no longer available to you. This isn't a 'Loop', simply an array of post object.

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

#### In response to your questions

1. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter your main query. Use a separate `WP_Query` object (method 2) for secondary loops in the template pages.
2. If you want to alter the query of the main loop, use `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: So is there any scenario when one would go straight to get_posts() rather than WP_Query?

Comment: @drtanz - yes. Say for instance you don't need pagination, or sticky posts at the top - in these instances `get_posts()` is more efficient.

Comment: But wouldn't that add an extra query where we could just modify pre_get_posts to modify the main query?

Comment: @drtanz - you wouldn't be using `get_posts()` for the main query - its for secondary queries.

Comment: In your WP_Query example, if you change $my_secondary_loop->the_post(); to $my_post = $my_secondary_loop->next_post(); you can avoid having to remember to use wp_reset_postdata() as long as you use $my_post to do what you need to do.

Comment: @Privateer Not so, `WP_Query::get_posts()` sets `global $post;`

Comment: @StephenHarris I just looked through the query class and don't see it. I checked mostly because I never use wp_reset_postdata because I always do queries this way. You are creating a new object and all of the results are contained within it.

Comment: @Privateer - sorry, typo, `WP_Query::the_post()`, see: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/759f3d894ce7d364cf8bfc755e483ac2a6d85653/wp-includes/query.php#L3732

Comment: @StephenHarris Right =) If you use next_post() on the object instead of using the_post, you don't step on the global query and don't need to remember to use wp_reset_postdata afterwards.

Comment: @Privateer Ah, my apologies, seemed to have confused myself. You are right (but you would not be able to use any functions which refer to the global `$post` e.g. `the_title()`, `the_content()`).

Comment: True =) I never use any of those so I don't miss them.

Comment: @urok93 I sometimes `get_posts()` when I need to get ACF related posts, especially if there's only one. Thought to standardize my templates I'm considering rewriting them as WP_Query instances.

Comment: @urok93 I almost always use get_posts because it is stateless, whereas WP_Query messes with who knows what global variables.

Answer (score 65):

There are two different contexts for loops:

- **main** loop that happens based on URL request and is processed before templates are loaded
- **secondary** loops that happen in any other way, called from template files or otherwise

Problem with `query_posts()` is that it is secondary loop that tries to be main one and fails miserably. Thus forget it exists.

## To modify main loop

- don't use `query_posts()`
- use `pre_get_posts` filter with `$query->is_main_query()` check
- alternately use `request` filter (a little too rough so above is better)

## To run secondary loop

Use `new WP_Query` or `get_posts()` which are pretty much interchangeable (latter is thin wrapper for former).

## To cleanup

Use `wp_reset_query()` if you used `query_posts()` or messed with global `$wp_query` directly - so you will almost never need to.

Use `wp_reset_postdata()` if you used `the_post()` or `setup_postdata()` or messed with global `$post` and need to restore initial state of post-related things.

Comment: Rarst meant `wp_reset_postdata()`

Answer (score 25):

There are legitimate scenarios for using `query_posts($query)`, for example:

1. You want to display a list of posts or custom-post-type posts on a page (using a page template)
2. You want to make pagination of those posts work

Now why would you want to display it on a page instead of using an archive template?

1. It's more intuitive for an administrator (your customer?) - they can see the page in the 'Pages'
2. It's better for adding it to menus (without the page, they'd have to add the url directly)
3. If you want to display additional content (text, post thumbnail, or any custom meta content) on the template, you can easily get it from the page (and it all makes more sense for the customer too). See if you used an archive template, you'd either need to hardcode the additional content or use for example theme/plugin options (which makes it less intuitive for the customer)

Here's a simplified example code (which would be on your page template - e.g. page-page-of-posts.php):

```php
/**
 * Template Name: Page of Posts
 */

while(have_posts()) { // original main loop - page content
  the_post();
  the_title(); // title of the page
  the_content(); // content of the page
  // etc...
}

// now we display list of our custom-post-type posts

// first obtain pagination parametres
$paged = 1;
if(get_query_var('paged')) {
  $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif(get_query_var('page')) {
  $paged = get_query_var('page');
}

// query posts and replace the main query (page) with this one (so the pagination works)
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'my_post_type', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'paged' => $paged));

// pagination
next_posts_link();
previous_posts_link();

// loop
while(have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  the_title(); // your custom-post-type post's title
  the_content(); // // your custom-post-type post's content
}

wp_reset_query(); // sets the main query (global $wp_query) to the original page query (it obtains it from global $wp_the_query variable) and resets the post data

// So, now we can display the page-related content again (if we wish so)
while(have_posts()) { // original main loop - page content
  the_post();
  the_title(); // title of the page
  the_content(); // content of the page
  // etc...
}
```

Now, to be perfectly clear, we could avoid using `query_posts()` here too and use `WP_Query` instead - like so:

```
// ...

global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('your query vars here')); // sets the new custom query as a main query

// your custom-post-type loop here

wp_reset_query();

// ...
```

But, why would we do that when we have such a nice little function available for it?

Comment: Brian, thanks for that. I've been struggling to get pre_get_posts to work on a page in EXACTLY the scenario you describe: client needs to add custom fields/content to what otherwise would be an archive page, so a "page" needs to be created; client needs to see something to add to nav menu, as adding a custom link escapes them; etc. +1 from me!

Comment: That can also be done using "pre_get_posts". I did that to have a "static front page" listing my custom post types in a custom order and with a custom filter. This page is also paginated. Check out this question to see how it works: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/how-to-use-a-custom-post-type-archive-as-front-page/30854

So in short, there is still no more legitimate scenario for using query_posts ;)

Comment: Because "It should be noted that using this to replace the main query on a page can increase page loading times, in worst case scenarios more than doubling the amount of work needed or more. While easy to use, the function is also prone to confusion and problems later on." Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: THis answer is all kinds of wrong. You can create a "Page" in WP with the same URL as the Custom post type. EG if your CPT is Bananas, you can get a page named Bananas with the same URL. Then you'd end up with siteurl.com/bananas. As long as you have archive-bananas.php in your theme folder, then it will use the template and "override" that page instead. As stated in one of the other comments, using this "method" creates twice the workload for WP, thus should NOT ever be used.

Answer (score 11):

I modify WordPress query from functions.php:

```
//unfortunately, "IS_PAGE" condition doesn't work in pre_get_posts (it's WORDPRESS behaviour)
//so you can use `add_filter('posts_where', ....);`    OR   modify  "PAGE" query directly into template file

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'myFunction' );
function myFunction($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )  {
        if (  $query->is_category ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'my_postType' ) );
            add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'MyFilterFunction_1' ) && $GLOBALS['call_ok']=1; 
        }
    }
}
function MyFilterFunction_1($where) {
   return (empty($GLOBALS['call_ok']) || !($GLOBALS['call_ok']=false)  ? $where :  $where . " AND ({$GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts}.post_name NOT LIKE 'Journal%')"; 
}
```

Comment: would be interested to see this example but where clause is on custom meta.

Answer (score 8):

*Just to outline some improvements to the accepted answer since WordPress evolved over the time and some things are different now (five years later):*

> `pre_get_posts` is a filter, for altering any query. It is most often used to alter only the 'main query':

Actually is an action hook. Not a filter, and it will affect any query.

> The main query appears in your templates as:

```
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();
       //The loop
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Actually, this is also not true. The function `have_posts` iterates the `global $wp_query` object that is not related *only* to the main query.  `global $wp_query;` may be altered with the secondary queries also.

```
function have_posts() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->have_posts();
}
```

> ## get_posts()
>
> This is essentially a wrapper for a separate instance of a WP_Query object.

Actually, nowadays `WP_Query` is a class, so we have an instance of a class.

---

**To conclude: At the time @StephenHarris wrote most likely all this was true, but over the time things in WordPress have been changed.**

Comment: Technically, it's all filters under the hood, actions are just a simple filter. But you are correct here, it's an action that passes an argument by reference, which is how it differs from more simple actions.

Comment: `get_posts` returns an array of post objects, not a `WP_Query` object, so that is indeed still correct. and `WP_Query` has always been a class, instance of a class = object.

Comment: Thanks, @Milo, correct from some reason I had oversimplified model in my head.